# How to perform join operation when three tables are linked?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables in database tbProduct, tbCompany, tbCompanyProduct

tbProduct

- Product (id feild)
- ProductX (product name)

tbCompany

- CompanyId
- CompanyName

tbCompanyProduct

- Company (F.K for Company Id)
- Product (F.K for Product Id)

Now I have to perform join operation for fetching all the products assigned to a company i.e on the basis of @companyid parameter...
Please help me !!!

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will look like this.....It is simple join between three tables...

```
SELECT comp.CompanyName, prod.ProductX
FROM tbCompanyProduct compPro
INNER JOIN tbCompany comp ON compPro.Company = comp.CompanyId
INNER JOIN tbProduct prod ON prod.Product = compPro.Product
WHERE comp.CompanyId = yourCompanyId
```